# PHP curl request to localhost file in same folder returns no data and no errors

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to use proper backend/frontend separation by having my front-end code interact with the DB only through HTTP calls. I remember getting this working in the past and thought it was an Apache setting of some kind so I set my config to this and restarted:

```
DocumentRoot "d:/working/htdocs"
<Directory "d:/working/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

This is my php function (based on various sources online):

```php
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = url_root.'backend.php';
        echo $url;

        switch ($method)
        {
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                if ($data)
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
                break;
            default:
                if ($data)
                    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
        }

        // Optional Authentication:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);


        if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
            pre_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
            echo 'Cerr: '.curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
```

The result of a call to get a user is this:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://localhost:80/proj/backend.php?get_user=1
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 354
    [request_size] => 95
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.031
    [namelookup_time] => 1.0E-6
    [connect_time] => 0.016
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.016
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.031
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => ::1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => ::1
    [local_port] => 63492
)

Cerr:
```

There is no data that I can see that tells me what the problem is or how to fix it. No errors, no codes, no feedback of any kind, just deadness. I've been looking at SO posts for an hour and all them have essentially the same information: "just check the errors" or "add this setting" or something... all of which I've tried. Now what?

Comment: what response where you expecting from `backend.php` ? Let's say you ran the same curl command directly on the command line, what do you get?

Comment: Awwwww.... crap! I had an error with a two functions with the same name, but it wouldn't give me any errors so I didn't notice. When I ran the backend  manually via GET vars and it returned nothing, I was able to little by little trace the error. Bah! Thank you!

Comment: One thing you can do is turn on errors by adding these two lines on top of your code. `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` This will help you in the future.

Comment: I have that, but not E_ALL. I wouldn't think a dual function would be under NOTICES... either way if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. I could delete, but it wouldn't help anyone who was seeing the same as me.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable that you write the answer you came up with, then accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt use error_reporting(E_ALL). I didn't think critical errors would be under "NOTICES" and turned that off in my testing, but when I changed it to E_ALL, it showed me I had two functions with the same name. Sigh...